# Yii2 to make a button disappear after clicked

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to make a report button that a user can click only once. After clicking it will disappear and show a text saying "Already Reported" instead.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is a JS/Ajax question and has nothing to do with Yii.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know @robsch

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery. Add a class "yourclass" to your button and add following script to your js file

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('click', '.yourclass', function(){
             $(this).after("Already Reported");
             $(this).remove();
         });
    });
```